# PDF file comparision with web pages

Tags: testing, automation

We have a requirement of testing Content of PDF files with the data displayed in web page of our application. Can anybody suggest an automation tool or approach which we can using for automating the above scenario.

Comment: If you're partial to ruby: https://github.com/prawnpdf